# AngularJS modal doesn't return created value to the array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to open a modal window, create a new record and this record put to the array with all records from the database.

Here's the link for opening the modal:

```
<a href="" ng-click="openModalNew()">New Post (AngularJS)</a>
```

Here the form in the modal window:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" class="new_post ng-pristine ng-valid ng-binding" id="new_post">
  <input data-ng-model="post.id" id="id" name="post[id]" type="hidden" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
  <div class="form-group ng-binding">
    <label for="post_title">Title</label>
    <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="post_title" name="post[title]" ng-model="post.title" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="post_body">Body</label>
    <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" id="post_body" name="post[body]" ng-model="post.body" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="post_starred">Starred</label>
    <input id="post_starred" name="post[starred]" ng-model="post.starred" type="checkbox" value="1" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <button data-ng-click="saveForm(post)" id="btnsubmit">
      <span class="ng-binding">Create</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And here the controller:

```
app.factory('Posts', function($resource){
 return $resource('/posts.json', {}, {
    query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
    create: { method: 'POST' },
    save: { method: 'POST' } // testing this
 })
});

app.factory('Post', function($resource) {
    return $resource("/posts/:id.json", { id: '@id' }, {
        'create':  { method: 'POST' },
        'index':   { method: 'GET', isArray: true, responseType: 'json' },
        'update':  { method: 'PUT' },
    });
});

app.controller("PostsCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$resource', 'Posts', 'Post', '$location', '$modal', '$timeout', function($scope, $http, $resource, Posts, Post, $location, $modal, $timeout) { 
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.posts = Posts.query(function ()  {
      $scope.loading = false;
    });

    $scope.openModal = function() {
          $scope.$modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'angularjs/templates/testtt.html',
            controller: 'PostsCtrl',
        scope: $scope
          });
    };
        $scope.cancel = function() {
          $scope.$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };

    $scope.openModalNew = function(post) {
      if(post) {
            $scope.headline = 'Edit Post';
        $scope.post = post; // load values from database
        $scope.post.id = post._id.$oid;
        $scope.btn_text = 'Update Post';
        $scope.$modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'angularjs/templates/new_post.html',
          controller: 'PostsCtrl',
          scope: $scope
        });         
      } else {
        $scope.headline = 'Create New Post';
        $scope.post = {}; // set all inputs/vaues on default
        $scope.btn_text = 'Create New Post';
        $scope.$modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'angularjs/templates/new_post.html',
          controller: 'PostsCtrl',
          scope: $scope
        });
      }
    }

    $scope.saving = false;
    $scope.saveForm = function(post) {
      $scope.saving = true;
      $scope.btn_text = "Processing...";

      if (!post.id) { // new record
        var p = new Post(post);
        p.$save().then(function(response){ 
          //$scope.posts.push(angular.extend(p, {_id: response.id.$oid}));
          $scope.posts.push(response); // this works
          $scope.btn_text = "Done!"
          $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
          }, 500);
        });
    } else { // edit of existing record
      Post.update({ id: post.id,
            title: post.title,
            body: post.body,
            starred: post.starred }).$promise.then(function () {
              $scope.btn_text = "Done!"
              $timeout(function() {
                $scope.$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
              }, 500);
            });

        }

    };
    ...
```

And the view:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Body</th>
      <th>Starred</th>
      <th>Comments</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="post in posts">
      ...
```

The problem is that when I click on the **New Post** link, the modal window will appear, I enter the information and submit it - the record is created in database, the modal disappears (that's good), but the table with `posts` is not updated - there is not added this new record.

Why is that? Is the procedure of calling the modal window wrong? Do I need to add somewhere the `resolve` part (I am new to AngularJS)? Or do I work incorrectly with `$scope` inside the modal window?

I'd be very grateful for any help, cannot make this work.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Where is the query function? can u show it? u must be using a service here if i am not mistaken. And what do u mean your post is not updated? does your post in posts displays data?

Comment: Hi `aintno12u`, thanks for your comment. I updated the JS code and added the factories. `post in posts` return data, but if I add a new record through the modal window, this new record is not added to the `posts` loop, so I don't see this newly added record there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to pass the new array that is on scope back through the modal close event function.

```
$scope.$modalInstance.close($scope.posts);
```

from angular ui docs:

```
close(result) - a method that can be used to close a modal, passing a result

dismiss(reason) - a method that can be used to dismiss a modal, passing a reason

The event itself includes a parameter for the result/reason and a boolean parameter that indicates whether the modal is being closed (true) or dismissed.
```

plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/jd8ap4qU2fM5dv6foUty?p=preview